# maven can't find archetype in my repository

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create my own maven archetype.  For now, I'm going through this tutorial [here][1] without success.  I'm able to build the archetype project okay, but when I try to generate a project from that archetype I get the error below.  *Maven can't seem to find the archetype I created*.  Can any one spot my problem?  Is there some other recomended tutorial for createing a maven archetype?  Thanks.

Maven version 3.0.3

Build Error:

```
AR3Y35-LAPTOP:EclipseWS Albert$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeGroupId=com.myarch.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=component-archetype -DinteractiveMode=false 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Specified archetype not found.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.389s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 23 02:33:55 PDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.myarch.archetypes:component-archetype:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
AR3Y35-LAPTOP:EclipseWS Albert$
```

### prototype pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.myarch.templates</groupId>
    <artifactId>component-template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>

  <name>${group}</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

### archetype.xml

```xml
<archetype xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-1.0.0.xsd">
  <id>component-archetype</id>
  <sources>
    <source>src/main/java/App.java</source>
  </sources>
  <testSources>
    <source>src/test/java/AppTest.java</source>
  </testSources>
  <allowPartial>true</allowPartial>
</archetype>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed to include -DarchetypeVersion={my.archetype.version} in the mvn archetpe:generate command

Comment: I had this part wrong. I was specifying the wrong archetypeVersion.

Answer (score 19):

For using a customized archetype, there has to be an entry made in the `archetype-catalog.xml` file which resides in the `.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml` in your home directory. For doing so, you need to install the archetype by using the following command:

```
mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog
```

After that, you will be able to use your new archetype while creating a new Maven project with the `mvn archetype:generate` command.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that:
- `update-local-catalog` goal created file `~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml`
- `generate` goal searches for file `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`
copying the file was a workaround. Not sure how I've fixed this. Sure now with maven 3.5.4 everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the mvn install resolves the problem, after executing that from idea the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, You have to search for your groupId is accessible in the below link or not

> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

I found out I had typo error then I've got error.