# Archetype for EJB + JBoss7 Porj

Tags: java, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

I want to build a project using Maven. I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Having Used this archetype my Maven gave me this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate
>   (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does
>   not exist (org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:3.0.2.Final) -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]

Tell me, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to read more on Maven and how to use maven archetype.

Please look as this 
[maven-archetype-webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965477/maven-archetype-webapp-directory-structure)
[maven-cant-find-archetype-in-my-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527060/maven-cant-find-archetype-in-my-repository?rq=1)

**you can generate a maven projet outside from your IDE with the architype of your choice and import the project as maven project later into your prefered IDE**

**Example 1**
groudId:artifactId

```
org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp
```

**Description**
    An archetype that generates a starter Java EE 6 webapp project for JBoss AS 7. The project is an EAR, with an EJB-JAR and WAR

**Example 2**
groudId:artifactId

org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp

**Description**
        An archetype that generates a starter Java EE 6 webapp project for JBoss AS 7

**Example 3**
groudId:artifactId

```
org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype
```

**Description**
    An archetype that generates a starter Java EE 6 webapp project for JBoss AS 7.1 [by default] or EAP 6 [if the "enterprise" property is true]

Comment: Festus, you're too kind)) I use another archetype at working comp, I have a success: Maven build a project structure with assigned archetype, I create my maven-modules (multimodule-maven-project) and after all these I can install using Maven. But I failed to build a project structure with archetype that I gave...

Comment: @nightin_gale i don't understand your strategy. Can you explain it a little bit to me

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527060/maven-cant-find-archetype-in-my-repository?rq=1

Comment: Festus Tamakloe, I have a very plain strategy as you can subsequently see.
I found that archetype and wanna use it in my dependencies. But I've got described error.
Frankly speaking, I wanna create multi-maven-module using IDEA:
MainModule
|

Comment: My strategy is absolutely plain. I wanna use that archetype in my dependecies. But I've got the error, which I described.

Frankly speakng, I wanna create a such structure:

MainModule
|
|-Module1.jar+pom.xml
|
|-Module2.jar+pom.xml
|
|-pom.xml

When I create Maven-proj in IDEA, IDE let me choose archetype in local maven repository. But there is no any suitable for me. My friend gave me that archetype. But it is still not working. You see?
If you had any working arch, I would ask you to prise me with it)))

P.S. I use IDEA 12.1.6 + EJB 3 + JBoss 7.1.1Final + Oracle

Comment: @nightin_gale you can generate a projet outside from your IDE with the architype of your choice and import the project later to your prefered IDE

Comment: @nightin_gale. You are welcome. If this answer help you please just accept it and vote up. thanks